# JSON path for contains

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I have the below json

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
"version": "v2",
"title": "Portfolio"
},
"host": "portfolio.com",
"schemes": [
"https"
],
"paths": {
"/v2/clients/{clientId}/assets": {
"get": {
"tags": [
"assets"
```

There are multiple paths I want to extract but they all start `/v2/clients` so what Im looking for is everything that starts with `/v2/clients` but none of the sub-data that sits the below, just the full paths between the ""

I am using jmeter JSON extractor and if I use $.paths it starts at this point but brings through all the mass amount of sub-data. I've tried looking around stackoverflow but can't find exactly what I am looking for. Any help appreciated

Comment: Your json sample is not valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest would be going for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/)

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def index = 1
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).paths.each { path ->
       if (path.getKey().startsWith('/v2')) {
           vars.put('path_' + index, path.getKey())
           index++
       }
   }
   ```
3. That's it, you will have [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

   ```
   path_1=/v2/clients/{clientId}/assets
   path_2=/v2/foo/bar
   path_3=/v2/baz/qux
   etc.
   ```

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Another question top of this. Do you know how i can remove all the other data surrounding the paths and also the path_1, path-2 etc so it only shows the paths?

Comment: I'm not getting your question, you need to show what is the source data and the desired outcome and better in a new thread than in comments